# Vuesjs Getting v-for length of an Array

Tags: vue.js, graphql

[image]

I want to  render totalCount on VueJs

Here is my Grapql Api

```
query{
  allStudents{
    totalCount
    edges{
      node{
        id
        lastName
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is sample HTML Code

```
  <div>
                <p class="card-text text-right">Total Students</p>
                <div class="fluid-container">
                  <h3 class="card-title font-weight-bold text-right mb-0" v-for="(value, totalCount) in Objects"> {{totalCount}}: {{value}} </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That property is accessible in vue via `this.directory.totalCount` and in the html as `{{this.directory.totalCount}}`.

```html
<div>
    <p class="card-text text-right">Total Students</p>
    <div class="fluid-container">
        <h3 class="card-title font-weight-bold text-right mb-0"
           v-for="(value, totalCount) in Objects"> 
             {{directory.totalCount}}: {{value}}
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved `{{ directory.totalCount }}`